# массивы в react, ts и их вывод в верстку

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

у меня есть массив такого типа

```
{
  "cities": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "img": "...",
      "city": "город",
      "numTour": 2,
      "tours": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "",
          "price": 0,
          "time": 39,
          "comments": [
            {
              "id":1,
              "img":"...",
              "name": "Petrov popov 1",
              "com" : "какой то коментарий 1"
            },
            {
              "id":2,
              "img":"...",
              "name": "Petrov popov 2",
              "com" : "какой то коментарий 2"
            },
            {
              "id":3,
              "img":"...",
              "name": "Petrov popov 3",
              "com" : "какой то коментарий 3"
            }
          ],
          "subscribe": false
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "",
          "price": 0,
          "time": 39,
          "comments": [
            {
              "id":1,
              "img":"...",
              "name": "Petrov popov 1",
              "com" : "какой то коментарий 1"
            },
            {
              "id":2,
              "img":"...",
              "name": "Petrov popov 2",
              "com" : "какой то коментарий 2"
            },
            {
              "id":3,
              "img":"...",
              "name": "Petrov popov 3",
              "com" : "какой то коментарий 3"
            }
          ],
          
          "subscribe": false
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "",
          "price": 0,
          "time": 39,
          "comments": [
            {
              "id":1,
              "img":"...",
              "name": "Petrov popov 1",
              "com" : "какой то коментарий 1"
            },
            {
              "id":2,
              "img":"...",
              "name": "Petrov popov 2",
              "com" : "какой то коментарий 2"
            },
            {
              "id":3,
              "img":"...",
              "name": "Petrov popov 3",
              "com" : "какой то коментарий 3"
            }
          ],
          "subscribe": false
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "",
          "price": 0,
          "time": 39,
          "comments": [
            {
              "id":1,
              "img":"...",
              "name": "Petrov popov 1",
              "com" : "какой то коментарий 1"
            },
            {
              "id":2,
              "img":"...",
              "name": "Petrov popov 2",
              "com" : "какой то коментарий 2"
            },
            {
              "id":3,
              "img":"...",
              "name": "Petrov popov 3",
              "com" : "какой то коментарий 3"
            }
          ],
          "subscribe": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

как мне интегрировать информацию из массива в верстку но не каждого под массива а только 1,2,3 или 4. Пробовал вот так но выводит все массивы

```
                {
                    data?.tours.flatMap(tour => tour.comments.map((com) => (
                        <div className='item__comments' key={com.id}>
                        <div>
                            <img className='logo__person' alt='' src=''/>
                            <div className='name__person'>
                                <h1>
                                {com.name}
                                </h1>
                                <p>★ ★ ★ ★ ★</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p className='comments__person'>
                            {com.com}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                        )))
                }
```

Comment: Из вопроса не понятно, что идет не так и какого результата вы хотите достичь... в вопросе речь о каких то 1,2,3 и 4, однако в примере id ровно 1,2 3 4, вложенность не более 3х, элементов с подмассивом 4... отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте больше подробностей